# Rails: Render in *.js.erb doesn't execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code in my js.erb file

```
$("<%=j render(:partial => "phone/phone_fields" , :phone => @phone ,:token => tokenizer, :exists => false) %>").hide().appendTo('.contacts').slideDown();
```

The controller that calls it passes the @phone variable while tokenizer is a helper. If I make tokenizer and @phone as an alert message it works but when i use it inside a render statement, it does nothing. It doesn't execute at all. It doesn't even give an error or something..

I have tried many variations such as calling the js render statement inside the controller and the result is passed down to the js file and still doesn't work. But i was wondering why it works in one of my helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this while rendering partial from "js.erb" files :

```
<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "phone/phone_fields",
:phone => @phone ,:token => tokenizer, :exists => false)) %>
```